# Can I run .NET 4.0 web applications on Windows Server 2003?

Tags: .net

Does .NET 4.0 work in windows server 2003 and iis 6?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, but you might run into some problems. See [here](http://johan.driessen.se/archive/2010/04/13/getting-an-asp.net-4-application-to-work-on-iis6.aspx).

Answer (score 7):

### System Requirements

- **Supported Operating Systems:**

  - Windows 7;
  - Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 2;
  - Windows Server 2008;
  - Windows Server 2008 R2;
  - Windows Vista Service Pack 1;
  - Windows XP Service Pack 3
  - Windows XP SP3
  - Windows Server 2003 SP2
  - Windows Vista SP1 or later
  - Windows Server 2008 (not supported on Server Core Role)
  - Windows 7
  - Windows Server 2008 R2 (not supported on Server Core Role)
- **Supported Architectures:**

  - x86
  - x64
  - ia64 (some features are not supported on ia64 for example, WPF)
- **Hardware Requirements:**

  - Recommended Minimum: Pentium 1 GHz or higher with 512 MB RAM or more
  - Minimum disk space:

    - x86 – 850 MB
    - x64 – 2 GB
- **Prerequisites:**

  - Windows Installer 3.1 or later
  - Internet Explorer 5.01 or later

[Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (Web Installer)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9cfb2d51-5ff4-4491-b0e5-b386f32c0992&displaylang=en)