# Deploying to Windows Server 2003

Tags: visual-studio, f#, console-application, windows-server-2003

Using visual studio 2013 on a windows 8 machine I created a F# console application. The app runs fine on the dev machine. But when I build a debug release and export it to a windows 2003 server and attempt to run, I continually get the error: `not a valid win32 application` even though the build configuration is set to "any cpu". Does anyone know how to solve this error? Thanks.

Comment: Which .NET framework are your targeting? Is it installed on the server? .NET 4.5 is not possible on Windows Server 2003. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb822049(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I run .NET 4.0 web applications on Windows Server 2003?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3347722/can-i-run-net-4-0-web-applications-on-windows-server-2003)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using .NET Framework 4.5 wich is not compatible with Windows Server 2003.

If you are not using anything from .NET 4.5 you can change on Visual Studio the framework targeted by the application to 4 and then run it on Windows Server 2003.

Also, here is the list of requirements for .NET Framework 4.5
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww%28v=vs.110%29.aspx